# YouTube id contents in TYPO3 Flux FAL Object

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I have a YouTube Video as a FAL Object and i need the YouTube id in my Fluid Template.

In a FileReference Object it is possible to get the id via `{file.contents}`.

But i can't find the YouTube id in the FAL Array from a `flux:field.inline.fal`
In my flux Content Template i get the Video FAL Array like this:

```
{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'settings.falimage', record:record) -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'image')}
```

In the recieved Array i only find the url to the YouTube Video. Is there a getter or ViewHelper for that?

**My Setup:**

- TYPO3 9.5.9
- Flux 9.2.0
- VHS 5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the failed attempt to use the VHS PregMatchViewHelper (https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/development/Variable/PregMatchViewHelper.html) in conjunction with the pattern https://gist.github.com/ghalusa/6c7f3a00fd2383e5ef33 i ended up creating an own ViewHelper that finds the YouTube id from an url:

```php
<?php

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;


/**
 * A view helper for rendering the YouTube Id from an url
 *
 * = Examples =
 *
 * <code>
 * {nc:youTubeId(url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpOVYePk6mM')}
 * </code>
 * <output>
 * zpOVYePk6mM
 * </output>
 */
class YouTubeIdViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * Initialize arguments
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        $this->registerArgument('url', 'string', 'YouTube url', true);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return string youtube id
     */
    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        $url = $arguments['url'];
        preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
        $youtube_id = $match[1];

        return $youtube_id;
    }
}
```